# Swift: value of type (_)->has no member 'Generator'

Tags: xcode, swift

I have this code to generate a RGB value from a hex code in Swift 2.0

```
    class func colorWithHex(hexString: String?, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor? {

    if let hexString = hexString {

        var error : NSError? = nil

        let regexp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern:"\\A#[0-9a-f]{6}\\z", options: [.CaseInsensitive])

        let thrange = NSMakeRange(0, count(hexString))

        let thcount = regexp.numberOfMatchesInString(hexString, options: .ReportProgress, range: thrange)

        if thcount != 1 {

            return nil
        }

        var rgbValue : UInt32 = 0

        let scanner = NSScanner(string: hexString)

        scanner.scanLocation = 1
        scanner.scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

        let red   = CGFloat( (rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat( (rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue  = CGFloat( (rgbValue & 0xFF) ) / 255.0

        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }
```

however, it's throwing an error, I think this might be because the code was written for Swift 1.2 but I don't understand the Swift language well enough yet to parse what this error is trying to tell me.

The line `let thrange = NSMakeRange(0, count(hexString))` throws an error on `count(hexString)` saying `value of type '(_)-> _'has no member 'Generator'` what does this mean?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.0 `count()` was removed and in its place you now use `hexString.characters.count`